# Made a mistake in scheduling interview date

Tags: interviewing

I was emailed for an interview last week programmed to be a day in which I had a very important meeting at work.

I replied with a very well written email explaining why I couldn't come and suggesting alternative dates.

I made a mistake with those dates, I was looking at last year's calendar not this year, so they are wrong by one day.

I made another email explaining my mistake but they haven't replied. What are my possible actions besides waiting for a reply?

This is a very important opportunity to me so I don't want to mess up (more).

Comment: How long have you been waiting for a reply?

Comment: I sent it on friday and corrected myself this morning (GMT+1). It is too soon for a reply I know, but I want to prepare for all scenarios.

Comment: You'll have to give them some more time - unless the proposed dates are in this very week

Comment: @morsor Well that's the issue. The dates *are* in this very week. They wanted the interview on thursday and with the correction I proposed friday, monday and tuesday...

Comment: Do you need a couple of days notice in advance (for traveling)? If so, you'll need to contact them Tuesday morning.

Comment: @morsor I don't need to travel. But I do need to have advance notice so I can take leave from my job. I can't take leave without a few days of notice (except if I have a very good reason)

Comment: Can you call them?  Having a reasonable conversation would be the quickest way to get a answer.

Comment: All good they answered in time :) I will leave the question nonetheless since it may be relevant to someone else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do nothing.**

You sent some dates, and then you sent come corrected dates. Do the recruiter the favour of assuming they read both emails and are setting dates accordingly. That's the most likely scenario. The likelihood is this won't delay them setting a date by much.

If they come back offering a date that is impossible for you, be sure to respond immediately and point out your previous email.